# Why won't apply reduce my single-column DataFrame to a Series?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm getting the error

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I'm not sure why. The `samples` is a (3681, 58) DataFrame. `predictions` ends up being a (3681, 1) DataFrame as well, instead of a Series.

```
def sigmoid(weights, sample):
    return 1 / (1 + (np.exp(-sample.dot(weights))))


def predict_sigmoid(weights, sample, th):
    return 0 if sigmoid(weights, sample) < th else 1


def calculate_acc(predictions, targets):
    """Calc. the ACC between the predictions and the targets for the given DataFrame using the given weight vector."""
    return 1 - sum([0 if (predictions.iloc[i] == targets.iloc[i]) else 1 for i in range(len(targets))]) / len(targets)


def calculate_acc_regression(samples, targets, weights, f=predict_sigmoid, th=0.5):
    """Calc. the ACC between the predictions and the targets for the given DataFrame using the given weight vector."""
    predictions = samples.apply(lambda x: f(weights, x, th), axis=1, result_type='reduce')
    return calculate_acc(predictions, targets)
```

Comment: The issue is `predictions.iloc[i] == targets.iloc[i]`.  It's returning a Series instead of a single boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Since prediction is a DataFrame:

```
predictions.iloc[i] == targets.iloc[i]
```

is a Series rather than a boolean.

Perhaps you want to use equals?

```
predictions.iloc[i].equals(targets.iloc[i])
```

Comment: I guess what I'm really asking is why doesn't the line of code `predictions = samples.apply(lambda x: f(weights, x, th), axis=1, result_type='reduce')` set predictions as a Series so that `predictions.iloc[i] == targets.iloc[i]` compares two integers?

Comment: I also get the error `AttributeError: 'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'equals'` when using `.equals()`.

Comment: If one of these is expected to be an int64, you should use `.all()` on the resulting Series

Comment: Alright. Why is `predictions` a DataFrame here instead of a Series? I apply a reducing lambda function to each row of `samples` and I use the `result_type='reduce'` in the function call. I was expecting that `predictions` should be a Series of integers and that `predictions.iloc[i]` would always return a single integer.

Comment: @matthiasdenu it was in the original screenshot